# Mono: application not running when web.config in subfolder

Tags: linux, asp.net, mono, xsp2

I run [ASP.NET on Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

I wanted to run blogengine:
http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/


I downloaded, put it in `/var/www/blogengine`, on the console went to `/var/www/blogengine` and started xsp2.

I went to `http://localhost:8080`, and it ran without problems.

Then I stopped xsp2, went to `/var/www` and started xsp2.

I went to `http://localhost:8080/blogengine`

It ended with a strange  error:

> The section  can't be defined in this configuration file (the allowed definition context is 'MachineToApplication'). (/var/www/blogengine/Web.Config line 9)

The problem seems to be that it stops working as soon as the xsp2 root folder is anything else than the application root folder...

Do I have to config anything? Or what else is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. You must run xsp in the root of your web application or specific a path to be root.

For example...

```
xsp2 --root /var/www/blogengine
```